# E: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this piece of python code in which I am trying to do some math on some data within a data frame based whether or not the binary variable of interest is 1. Originally I had this but it didn't work

```
if df['lei_vigorous_binary'] == 1:
    df['lei_vig_min'] = df['lei_vigorous_duration_hr'] * 60 + df['lei_vigorous_duration_mn']
    df['lei_vig_met_min'] = df['lei_vig_min'] * df['lei_vigorous_frequency'] * 8  #GPAQ Vigorous activity Multiplier

else:
    df['lei_vig_min'] = df['lei_vigorous_duration_mn']
    df['lei_vig_met_min'] = df['lei_vig_min'] * df['lei_vigorous_frequency'] * 8
```

Giving me an error stating TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
So I modified it and tried doing it this way

```
df.loc[df['lei_vigorous_binary'] == 1, ] = df.loc[df['lei_vigorous_binary'] == 1, 'lei_vigorous_duration_hr'] * 60 + df.loc[df['lei_vigorous_binary'] == 1, 'lei_vigorous_duration_mn']
            
df.loc[df['lei_vigorous_binary'] == 1, ] = df.loc[df['lei_vigorous_binary'] == 1, 'lei_vig_min'] * df.loc[df['lei_vigorous_frequency'] == 1, 'lei_vigorous_frequency'] * 8
```

This did not work and led to the error in the title. Any thoughts as to why this way isn't working?

Comment: Assuming `df` is a dataframe, I don't see anything there that should give you a hash error.  Which line, exactly, issued that error?   Is this inside an `apply`?  If not, what do you expect that very first line to do?  How can an entire column `== 1`?

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: The very first line issued the error to me. It isn't inside an apply either, it's part of a function I am writing. The entire column isn't only 1s, it has 0s in there too. I want to select those that have a 1 and modify those other variables listed within the if else statement by doing some math.